# Align html dropdown menu left (under the title)

Tags: html

I am currently struggling to align the dropdown menu I have created. I need it to align to the left as it is currently aligning to the centre. I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate my current code and the issue.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wu9gnsj5/

```
.menu {
     float: right;
     margin-top: 22px;
     margin-left: 45px;
     margin-right: 140px;
     padding:0;
     list-style: none;
     font-weight: 700;
}

.menu div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.menu div a {
    color: #42494e;
}

.header div.menu div a:hover {
    color: #e60000; 
}

.dropbtn {
  color: black;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top:100%;
  left: 0%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a css class that targets all `.menu > div` elements with `margin-left: 30px;`, *including* your dropdown.

You can override this by resetting the margin in your dropdown class.

```
.dropdown-content {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```